# target only one item from list on each click reactjs

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying to solve this exercise and I got stuck.

1. Show 10 posts from the API in the browser - Working
2. For each post show 3 related comments - Working

The problem is that when I click one Post from the feed, the click function will fetch and display the all other comments below the respective posts at the same time...What I'm trying to accomplish is to onClick display comment to the related post and hide it when clicked on other post.

Also I need to show a button "load more" every time a set of comments appears and fetch the latest 10 comments when clicked.

Any Help, Suggestions on how to keep things clean and readable would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance;

:)

Code Below:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const postsID = "/posts";
const commentsID = "/comments";
var postsURL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com${postsID}`;
var commentsURL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com${commentsID}`;

class Posts extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  posts: [],
  comments: [],
  expanded: false,
  commentsToShow: 3
};
this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
}
/*
showMoreComments() {

}
*/
clicked() {
  axios.get(commentsURL).then(res => {
    console.log("comments:", res);
   this.setState({ comments: res.data });
 });
}

componentDidMount() {
 axios.get(postsURL).then(res => {
   console.log("posts:", res);
   this.setState({ posts: res.data });
 });
}

render() {
  //console.log('VARIABLE WORKING!', postsURL);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="jumbotron-div col s12">
        <ul className="collection">
          {this.state.posts.slice(0, 10).map(post => (
            <div>
              <div key={post.id} onClick={this.clicked}>
                <h5>User ID: {post.id}</h5>
                <p>Post: {post.body}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ul className="collection">
                  {this.state.comments
                    .filter(comment => comment.postId === post.id)
                    .slice(0, 3)
                    .map(comment => (
                      <li key={comment.id}>
                        <p>Comment ID: {comment.postId}</p>
                        <p>Comment: {comment.body}</p>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
  );
}
}

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Post can show its comments or hide it, then it definetly needs its own state. Therefore, it needs to be an own component, e.g.:

```
 class Post extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { showComents: false };
   }

   render() {
     const { id, body, comments } = this.props;

     return (
         <div key={id} onClick={() => this.setState({showComments: true })}>
           <h5>User ID: {id}</h5>
           <p>Post: {body}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="collection">
            {this.state.showComments ? comments.slice(0, 3)
                .map(comment => (
                  <li key={comment.id}>
                    <p>Comment ID: {comment.postId}</p>
                    <p>Comment: {comment.body}</p>
                  </li>
                )) : ""}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
     );
   }
 }
```

Then use `<Post />` inside of Posts and pass down all the data the Post needs.

Comment: still doesnt work...maybe if you could give a better example?